# What does the expression 'your words have BRANDED my mind' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

***The line from [lyrics](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/queensofthestoneage/thebloodislove.html):***

> Your words have **branded** my mind

***Question:***

> What does the expression mean and especially meaning of the word [BRAND](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brand) in this context

***My guesses by context:***

> his mind became possessed with her words

Comment: The page you're linking to: verb, "1.1 Mark indelibly."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *brand* is a iron instrument with a unique symbol on one end, used to mark cattle by burning after being heated-up red hot.  The mark is permanent.

Compare with the words *burn in* - also used figuratively, but *brand* emphasizes the "permanent change" or "this leaves a mark" aspect.  I'm not sure if branding is painful/traumatic to cattle but it certainly is if done to human beings and that's another possible subtext of any figurative use.

> Your words have branded my mind

The writer/speaker is saying your words are going to permanently stay "on" my mind.

Comment: Yes, usually written as branded on my mind. Because otherwise it sounds like - as this does - branded like a product.